# Angular 5 Pre populating input=date from ISOstring>

Tags: html, angular, input, angular5

I'm trying to pre populate a date of birth input:

```
<input class="common" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" type="date" [(ngModel)]="account.date_of_birth" />
```

The variable is current set to `Tue Jul 16 1996 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

The issue is that the input isnt being set and just shows `dd/MM/yyyy`

I have tried with `value`, `datetime-local` (which doesnt work but I also dont want the time in the input)

Answer (score 0):

Use the date pipe. Try changing your `[ngModel]` binding as,

In your `.ts` file import the `DatePipe` and try the following,

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

public birthdate:any;

var datePipe = new DatePipe();
this.birthdate = datePipe.transform(date_of_birth, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Then you  can use `this.birthdate` in your `[(ngModel)]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but unfortunately it isnt filling the input value in :(

Comment: Thanks again but again it isn't populating the value, as this is similar to what was suggested above I may just move and put it in a text field with regex for now

Answer (score 0):

1. You can you inbuilt date pipe.
2. with using moment(account.date_of_birth).format("DD/MM/YYYY") in Component side.

Comment: Unfortunately built in pipe as the answer below suggested doesnt fill the value in, and at least for right now, using another package for this is a last resort if I am not able to get this to work, but thank you for the answer

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1b68eLdr/43694/) Please check it, I have create one example

Comment: [Check more option in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krishnavadan/1b68eLdr/43710/)